# Телефоны с одинаковым(-ыми) значение(-ями) ёмкости аккумулятора

Tags: орфография

Как будет правильно? Если не трудно, скажите какое тут правило.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагается такой вариант:

Телефоны с одинаковым значением ёмкости аккумуляторов (= телефоны с  аккумуляторами одинаковой емкости).

Answer (score 0):

Здесь действует правило согласования. Определение ( в данном случае "одинаковый") согласуется в роде и числе с определяемом словом ( в данном случае "значение").

Правильно: Телефоны с одинаковым  значением ёмкости аккумулятора.

```
       Телефоны с одинаковыми значениями ёмкости аккумулятора.
```